# Laravel - How to manual paginate but with max number of total count?

Tags: laravel

Currently, I have a lot of Joins and SubJoins with Group By etc.

**To make it short:** I cannot use paginate, because it is too slow (because of Group by). That is why I need to use pagination manually, however, I need to limit the total number of rows as well. With rows way above 10k, I want to have the maximum of a total of 300!

My current approach works suboptimal and I don't really know how to fix it:

```
return \DB::table('offers')
           ->alotOfQueries/joins
           ->...
           ->limit(300) //we show only a maximum of 300 offers
           ->get();
```

After the return, I'm manually creating the pagination.

I'll just leave the code as well here:

```
protected function paginate(Collection $offerings): LengthAwarePaginator
{
    $page = request()->page ?? 1;

    $perPage = $this->config->take;

    $offset = ($page * $perPage) - $perPage;

    return new LengthAwarePaginator(
        array_slice($offerings->all(), $offset, $perPage, true),
        $offerings->count(), 
        $perPage, 
        $page,
        [
            'path' => request()->url(),
            'query' => request()->query()
        ]
    );
}
```

This current approach is much faster than using paginate.

**But my problem is** it is still loading 300 rows.

**My goal is** to load only 18 rows per page. And calculate the correct total until it hits 300. It won't go above.

The numbers are taken from Airbnb, so I can show you this picture, so you maybe know what I'm after at:

[image]

Airbnb is always limiting it's max total to 300. Because 18 rows are loaded, we get 17 pages.

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: "This current approach is much faster than using paginate." - This seems backwards, since with pagination, you're only fetching the result set that you need, instead of 300+ records and then manually slicing the records. Unless your joins and such are fighting with the `COUNT()` query (pagination will perform two queries: count ALL records, then limit/offset for the current page). I'd suggest posting your actual query to see if it can be optimized.

Comment: Good morning @AkenRoberts, sorry for the late response. I'm going to add the sql queries. With debugbar I see that the query for `COUNT()` takes about 1.68 seconds... Before I used pagination, the whole ajax request took only about 0.75s...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for you, readers in the future. I'm lucky in that sense that I could limit my sub join ->limit(300)

With that I could now use paginate. Now it is not slow anymore at all!

I tested it against manual pagination like with:

```
return $offersQuery->offset($this->offset)
                           ->limit($this->perPage)
                           ->get();
```

and it does not matter what you are going to use.